# An Integral Equation for Lebesgue Measurable Functions

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, integral-equations

Let $f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be Lebesgue measurable with $f(0)=f(1)=0.$

Can we find a measurable function $g \colon [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ such that
$$ f(u) = \int_u ^1 \int_0 ^u g(s,t) \, ds \, dt $$
with
$$ g(s,t) = 0 \text{ for } s > t $$
$$ \int_0 ^1 \int_0 ^t g(s,t) \, ds \, dt =1 ? $$

All the assumptions of $f$ necessary, are they sufficient for existence of such a $g?$ If not, what more should one assume to obtain such a representation with a proper $g?$

I considered the case where $f$ is differentiable, maybe twice, and $g'$s of the form $g(s,t)=k(s) l(t)$ for some measurable $k$ and $l$ as special cases, yet I could not get to the general case.

Intuitively, $g$ can be thought as the density of a probability measure absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, and supported on the upper half of the unit square with respect to the diagonal. And we want to represent $f$ as the barycenter of the measure given by $g$ on the collection of random variables of the form $1_{[s,t]}$ for $s \leq t.$

Any help, hint or reference is appreciated greatly!

Comment: if $g \le 1$, then $$\int_0^1\int_0^tg(s,t)\,ds\,dt \le \int_0^1\int_0^t1\,ds\,dt = \frac 12$$ so you need to loosen your conditions somewhere. Also $\int_u^1\int_0^u g$ is continuous in $u$, so $f$ must be continuous. Correct those issues, though, and I think it would be possible.

Comment: Oh sorry, g was supposed to be a density, it can take any positive value. Could you provide me some intuition? And do you consider a constructive, more explicit approach or some other existential result?